# Why is my CSS wrapper yielding different widths depending on what elements it contains?

Tags: html, css

The navigation up top is moved further into the page when compared to the content below it. I can't figure out why it's doing that. It's almost as if the navigation has padding that forces it further in. I just edited this post to show the HTML and CSS of the file. Sorry about that!

```
<nav>

<div class="wrap">

  <div class="fl">

    <ul>

      <li>Supplement Tips</li>
      <li>Workout Routines</li>

    </ul>

  </div><!--fl-->

  <div class="fr">

    <a href="#"></a>

  </div><!--fr-->

</div><!--wrap-->
```

```
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="contentBlock">
```

**CSS**

```
  .wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 65%;
}
    nav {
  background: #FFF;
  border-bottom: #E4EAEA 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #E4EAEA, 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 60px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  opacity: .5;
}

/* Content */

.contentBlock {
  background: #FFF;
  border: #E4EAEA 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.contentHeader {
  padding: 24px 32px 24px 32px;
  border-bottom: #E4EAEA 1px solid;
}
.contentMain {
  padding: 0 32px 0 32px;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and CSS in a Code Snippet, so that we can see what's happening and what might be causeing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space is caused by the default `padding` on `<ul>`. You can set it to `padding-left: 0;` to make the navigation links align left.

Below is the default css of `<ul>` in chrome:

```
ul, menu, dir {
   display: block;
   list-style-type: disc;
   -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
   -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
   -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
   -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
   -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```